# Help improve my file upload method (Pyramid framework)

Tags: python, pylons, multipart, pyramid

Currently, I am using the following method for uploading files (via HTML form) in Pyramid.

```
if request.params.get('form.submitted'):

    upload_directory = os.getcwd() + '/myapp/static/uploads/'

    my_file = request.POST.get('thumbnail')
    saved_file = str(upload_directory) + str(my_file.filename)

    perm_file = open(saved_file, 'w')

    shutil.copyfileobj(my_file.file, perm_file)
    my_file.file.close()
    perm_file.close()
```

I am just wondering, is this a good way of saving file uploads, are there any security concerns with my method? How else can I improve my method. Thanks.

Comment: How does this go with large files?  I think for large files, you have to write in chunks.  I'm going to give your method a try though, thanks!

Comment: Hi, at the moment I have not tried this on large files. Mostly on files a under a meg. But please do report back if you try this on larger files and let me know how it goes, thanks.

Comment: use os.path.join(); better than string concatenation.

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to use something like werkzug's [`safe_join`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/security.py#L128) rather than just adding the upload directory to the given file name.  An attacker could create a POST with a filename of `../../../some/important/path` and cause this script to overwrite some file outside of your `upload_directory`.